# Drupal 8 View - get url field

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 8, path-aliases

How do I get the URL, not the link html for a taxonomy field in my view.

For Drupal 7 I found this ticket:
[How do I get the raw URL as a field in Views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37314/how-do-i-get-the-raw-url-as-a-field-in-views)

This mentions getting the content: path - but this doesn't show up as an option.

--- Updated ---

I am creating a block view, not sure that matters. I have no path option, I actually am not seeing any content in the field type options.

[image: Block view field options]

Comment: I am starting to think that this is a bug.

Comment: There is a feature request to add an option to the Entity link Views field plugin to generate a raw URL: https://www.drupal.org/node/2810097

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following.

1. Add Taxonomy ID field too your view
2. In your template or rewrite use the following as your url `{{url('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', {'taxonomy_term': tid})}}` or `{{path('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', {'taxonomy_term': tid})}}`

Comment: url() gives an absolute path.  

path() gives a relative path.  

  
See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates for more info about these functions.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem, I solved it by doing:

- Add a field "Taxonomy term: Term ID [hidden]" (make it hidden or not)
- Ensure that this field is in first position (if not, rearrange the fields order)
- Add a field "Global: Custom text"
- Put "{{ path('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', {'taxonomy_term': tid}) }}" (thx  @steven) in the "Text" section in the settings modal of this field.